# Edit a file in AppData folder using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, cordova

I wish to create/read/write/append to a file from a webpage created using HTML5, Javascript and CSS3. I need to do all this activity only in JavaScript.

```
"isFile": true,
"isDirectory": false,
"name": "readme.txt",
"fullPath": "file:///C:/Users/devarumc/AppData/Local/Packages/io.cordova.hellocordova_bzbj8h50hftv4/LocalState/readme.txt"
```

Is it possible to achieve this?
If yes, what would be the best strategy to achieve it? 
The requirement is edit the data in the above mentioned readme.txt file.

Comment: I was under the impression that PhoneGap came with file system APIs? I assumne you don't want to use those?

Comment: No, i want to create a small application to simulate the webpage where we can test it inside an iframe on the browser itself before building the code and porting the application to the device. So basically the final aim is to simulate those File APIs inside the desktop's browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this website, it will explain in details how to do it: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/

Remember that the user must allow your website to interact with files.